# Do superconductors experience any force from within a solenoid?

Tags: electricity, superconductivity

If I put a superconducting superconductor in the center of a solenoid and put a current through the solenoid, does the superconducting superconductor experience a force?

Comment: Is it just a piece of superconducting wire or a closed loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no force on a superconductor in a solenoid.

The first thing that happens when you turn on the solenoid is the superconductor develops a magnetic moment $-\frac{\alpha}{\mu_0}\vec{B}_0$ where $\vec{B}_0$ is the original field and $\alpha$ is a dimensionless constant characterizing the shape of the superconductor ($\alpha=3/2$ for a sphere), in other words, the superconductor acts like a perfect diamagnet.

Now we can ask how the moment interacts with the external magnetic field. If a field gradient is present the magnetic moment would experience a force. This is what happens in the case of a superconductor near a bar magnet; the field produced by the bar magnet is not uniform, there is a field gradient. In a solenoid the field is uniform so there is no force.

Another effect is the pinning of magnetic field to defects. This stabilizes superconductors levitating above bar magnets. But again there is no effect in a solenoid because the field is uniform.

Answer (score 0):

No, the superconductor will prevent magnetic field lines form going through the superconductor by creating an equal but opposite magnetic field itself (Meissner effect). The superconductor will thus form a magnet which can in principle interact with external magnetic fields. However, because the magnetic field of the solenoid is homogeneous, the superconductor will not experience any force from the external magnetic field.

Comment: This is not correct. The force of a uniform magnetic field on a magnetic dipole is zero.

Comment: @JamesRowland you are right, I edited my answer accordingly